# How to define a function that checks if a given list of booleans creates a square

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with this one part of a project:

> `is_square(board)`: Given a board as a list of lists of Booleans, check whether it
>   represents a square board with the same number of rows and columns. If
>   the rows don't all have the same number of items in them, or if the
>   number of rows does not match the number of columns, this function
>   returns False. Empty board is square.
>
> - Assume `board` is a list of lists of Booleans.
> - `is_square([[True,False,False],[False,False,False],[True,False,False]])` → True
> - `is_square([[True,False,False],[False,False,False]])` → False #2    rows    x   3 columns
> - `is_square([[True],[False,False],[True,False,False]])` → False

Could someone help me write a simple answer to this part?

Comment: The fact that the elements are Booleans seems to be irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty straightforward attempt:

```
def is_square(o):
    # If o is empty, it's a square - that takes care of the True
    # Otherwise, ensure that each of the elements inside o
    # contains the same number of elements as o itself.
    # To do that you just need to compare the length of each element with the length of o
    total_length = len(o)
    return all(len(elem) == total_length for elem in o)

# A somewhat more verbose equivalent would be as follows:
def is_square(o):
    total_length = len(o)
    for elem in o:
        # If there's any sublist that has a different length from the total, return False and we're done
        if len(elem) != total_length:
            return False
    # Empty lists and anything that made past that loop must be a square
    return True

o1 = [[True,False,False],[False,False,False],[True,False,False]]
o2 = [[True,False,False],[False,False,False]]
o3 = [[True],[False,False],[True,False,False]]

for o in o1, o2, o3:
    print(is_square(o))
```

Comment: Beat me to it... An explanation would be helpful though :)

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback guys, the original was just something I quickly put together